# font-awesome: what is the icon and its code used for reset password

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want to have a button and an icon on it for resetting password.

Currently I am using the following html code for edit. Using `bootstrap4`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" id="edit" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

So what code I can use for reset password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose one of them:

```css
.fa-passwd-reset > .fa-lock, .fa-passwd-reset > .fa-key  {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
<span class="fa-passwd-reset fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-undo fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span> <label>Reset Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="new-passwd" />
    <br>
    
    <span class="fa-passwd-reset fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-undo fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-key fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span> <label>Reset Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="new-passwd" />
```

Comment: I am not able to resize it properly to the proportion i want. Can you add few button adjacent and see (like add (plus) and edit ())

Comment: In my snippet it has a good size. What do you want to do?

Comment: and this is the code: https://i.imgur.com/oPtvno2.png

Comment: Add `fa-stuck` to all `<i>` class to get same size on each icon. https://pastebin.com/QpgXDd1j

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would take care of. Firstly, while choosing buttons I must try to follow some UX or material design that tells by design which buttons are primary and which buttons are secondary and their placements. Secondly, if there is ambiguity in the icon, then it's a good idea to add text.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" id="edit" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" type="button" id="edit" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" type="button" id="edit" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></button>
  </body>
</html>
```